# Не работает форма отправки

Tags: php, html, html5, веб-программирование, php7

Скачал готовый шаблон сайта при подключении формы отправки на e-mail возникли проблемы вот код

```js
<?php

if(isset($_POST['message'])){

 $name = $_POST['name'];
 $email = $_POST['email'];
 $message = $_POST['message'];
    
 
 $to      = 'you@example.com'; - как понимаю мой имейл
 $subject = 'Site Contact Form'; - как понимаю ссылка на сайт где будет  форма

 $headers = 'From: '. $email . "\r\n" .
    'Reply-To: '. $email . "\r\n" .
    'X-Mailer: PHP/' . phpversion();

 $status = mail($to, $subject, $message, $headers);

 if($status == TRUE){ 
  $res['sendstatus'] = 'done';
 
  //Edit your message here
  $res['message'] = 'Form Submission Successful';
    }
 else{
  $res['message'] = 'Failed to send mail. Please mail me to you@example.com';
 }
 
 
 echo json_encode($res);
}

?>
```

```html
<form action="assets/php/contact.php" id="contact-form" role="form" method="POST">
  <div class="ajax-hidden">
    <div class="form-group wow fadeInUp">
      <label class="sr-only" for="c_name">Name</label>
      <input type="text" id="c_name" class="form-control" name="c_name" placeholder="Name">
    </div>
    <div class="form-group wow fadeInUp" data-wow-delay=".1s">
      <label class="sr-only" for="c_email">Email</label>
      <input type="email" id="c_email" class="form-control" name="c_email" placeholder="E-mail">
    </div>
    <div class="form-group wow fadeInUp" data-wow-delay=".2s">
      <textarea class="form-control" id="c_message" name="c_message" rows="7" placeholder="Message"></textarea>
    </div>
    <button type="submit" class="btn btn-lg btn-block wow fadeInUp" data-wow-delay=".3s">Send Message</button>
  </div>
  <div class="ajax-response"></div>
</form>
```

Подключил форму, но она почему то не работает, на хостинге есть поддержка в чем может быть ещё причина?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

А чего ей работать то? У тебя везде name начинается с С (с_name, c_message), а в форме спрашивается есть ли message - вот он и не выполняется

Comment: Так вроде исправил https://jsfiddle.net/cd0g3fwe/1/, но всё равно не работает  в чем ещё может быть загвоздка?

Comment: Всё заработало вопрос решен